# Bash - kill process when other process dies

Tags: bash, process

My bash script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar my_app.jar &
python -m my_module
```

How do I kill the python process when the java process dies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ java -jar my_app.jar ; pkill -f my_module; } &
python -m my_module
```

You may want to further limit the selection of your Python process to be killed with additional switches.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple way

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m my_module &
pypid=$!
java -jar my_app.jar
kill $pypid
```

Comment: The python process needs to run in the foreground.